# pydev autocomplete for matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, autocomplete, pydev

Here is the code I write in pydev combined with eclipse.

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 fig=plt.figure()
```

as I know, 'fig'  is a instance of 'matplotlib.Figure' class，when I write :

```
  fig.
```

it seems pydev can't provide method calltip for fig. I cannot figure out what's going on, since for other module , like numpy, it works well.by the way, if i use a matlab-like interface, for example,

```
  plt.plot()
```

pydev does provide the calltip for function arguments.
    is there a way to solve this problem? I will appreciate it if anyone  give a solution .
    Forgive my poor english:-D

Answer (score 0):

`fig` is an instance of `matplotlib.figure.Figure` so what you can do is importing `import matplotlib.figure` and creating an instance of that. Then, writing `fig` to the editor, you should get the tooltip you want.

The following is a screenshot from Spyder, so I haven't actually tested it in pydev.

[image]

I am not aware of any other possibility. The reason is that for the requested functionality to work the editor would need to load all kinds of modules, which are not actually imported in the script.

Comment: you are correct. Since "import matplotlib.pyplot" enables usage of class Figure, I guess there must a import line like "from matplotlib.figure import Figure" in pyplot module .then it creates a function "figure" for the Matlab-like interface. Now, it seems pydev cannot trace back into matplotlib.figure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that some cases are too dynamic for PyDev to know about the actual type of the object that some method returns (which appears to be the case).

If you know the type, you can manually type it locally.

i.e.: Add the comment:

`#: :type fig: matplotlib.figure.Figure`

right before the `fig` assignment.

See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html for more details.